# How to show custom menu items in the WordPress android app?

Tags: admin, admin-menu, android

I hope this is the right .SE site for this question.

When on the road I want to use the [Android WordPress app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wordpress.android) to write short snippets of articles for later use.

My blog has some custom article sections, which are shown as extra admin menu items when I open it per browser:

[image]

*(In German localisation "Beiträge" means articles.)*

But when viewing the blog in my Android app, I only see the normal article section. Also other extra admin menu items are not shown either:

[image]

As I don't want to switch between the app and the browser (and to always re-login in browser), I would like to see those extra admin menu items in the app, too.

**Is there any possibility to show extra admin menu items in the Android WordPress app?**

If you need any further information, I'll gladly edit them in.

Comment: This may not be supported in the WordPress mobile app. I recommend asking at the forum https://android.forums.wordpress.org/

Comment: Q: "Is there any possibility to show extra admin menu items in the Android WordPress app?" A: No, you would need to fork the app and make a new version to support this. The app has no support for custom posts or any plugins that add such custom posts.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to change the code of the app, I have checked. It would be possible but hard to make your own version of the app that includes the added admin menus. If you would like to get that functionality added you should post on the forums as @RyanLoremIpsum said. But you may until then if it really bothers you want to stick to only using the mobile website. @Otto also said that you could fork the app and add functionality that would allow for menu integration with your plugin. But I would reccomend that if you are adding support for menus you should also try and integrate databases and other such plugin related data.

Comment: Otto has made a commentary about that too. It seems as he extracted it out of some FAQ. You may improve your answer with it, as it provides evidence. I will mark your answer as right then. :)